# Migrate one domain to another and force https on new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, migration, http-status-code-301

I am trying to migrate one domain to a new domain as well as force everything to https.

I have tried a few iterations using .htaccess with no luck.

One thing I tried was:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This redirects everything except the oldsite https links.

Also have tried other options like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.oldsite.com\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newsite.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Also with no luck.

I imagine I am missing something quite simple...any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides unescaped `.` character, your initial attempt is correct. To redirect one domain to another and switch to HTTPS connection, considering that there are other sites pointing to the same document root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE:**
Although the rule above is correct, redirection from https://www.oldsite.com to https://www.newsite.com didn't occur for original poster because newsite.com didn't have a valid certificate.

Comment: So the first rule works for http://www.oldsite.com but if a user browses to https://www.oldsite.com it does not get redirected to https://www.newsite.com

Comment: The first rule is to redirect all requests from `oldsite.com/somepage` to `https://www.newsite/somepage`. The second rule is to redirect `http://www.newsite.com/somepage` to `https://www.newsite.com/somepage`, if user enters non-secure URL `http://www.newsite.com/somepage` in the browser.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my response- If a user browses to `https://www.oldsite.com` it does not redirect to the new site...this is what I don't understand.  It seems like it should redirect to newsite.com whether the user is going to http or https but it does not.  This might have something to do with the fact that both oldsite and newsite have the same document root?

Comment: I guess I rushed with my response. Can you please confirm that `https://www.oldsite.com` and `http://ww.oldsite.com` point to the same folder and that is where your `.htaccess` resides? I looked at your initial attempt and don't see problems with it besides the first rule that should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newsite\.com$ [NC]`.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help!  Yes - both sites use the same directory, and share an .htaccess file.  I tried to change my first attempt (adding the \.com) and still had the same result.  `http://www.oldsite.com` gets forced to https on the newsite but `https://www.oldsite.com` does not get redirected at all and stays on oldsite.com.

Comment: Apparently we're missing something obvious. Can you please send me your contact info including the actual old and new site names using [this form](http://www.gyrocode.com/contacts/), let's see if we could figure it out.